# jQuery - dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a HTML form that contains:
1. textfield
2. select
3. check box
4. button to add 1-3 as another table row, see the [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fainick/vfurr/)

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        td {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#first").clone(false).removeAttr("id").appendTo($("table"));
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form>
            <div class="field-section">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Field name</th>
                        <th>Field type</th>
                        <th>Required</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="first">
                        <td><input type="text"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
                                <option>Text</option>
                                <option>Email</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button>+</button>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="create">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that each click submits the form.
**Questions**:
1. How solve this problem?
2. What is the best way to send the data from that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the button is within the form it defaults to a submit button you need to either `return false` or use the `preventDefault()` function within the click handler, Either one of these will prevent the default action of the element to trigger.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#first").clone(false).removeAttr("id").appendTo($("table"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfurr/2/)

To collect the data just use jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), if needing to send like through `.ajax`.

```
var data = $("#formID").serialize()
```

`serialize` will give you a name-value pair string of all elements.

Or to use the fields in your javascript use like `$("#formId input")` and `$("#formId select")` to capture all the input, select elements.

Answer (score 1):

As button is in form its default behavior is submit

So you have to add `type="button"` to button like

```
 <button type="button" >+</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vfurr/3/)

### OR

You need to use either `return false` or use the `preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#first").clone(false).removeAttr("id").appendTo($("table"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6V2N9/)